# Reading integer numbers over socket within buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer

I have declared buffer as

```
char buffer[256];
```

somewhere from the client, I'd want to fill this buffer with integer numbers as in array of integer.
coming back to the server code, I would have to read the integers in the buffer one by one separated by space.

```
read(sock, buffer, 255);
int r = atoi(buffer);
```

this will only read the first character in the buffer. any suggestion what I could use for this?

Comment: What sort of data is being sent over the socket? Binary integers or integer data encoded as ASCII?

Comment: @sfjac Its integer data encoded in ASCII.

Comment: It will need to be null terminated to call atoi. Are you sending the null?

Comment: @sfjac I guess yeah. I'm not sure what that means

Comment: If the transmitted message is just a number in ascii, then you'll get the length back from read. If you didn't send (char)0 in the stream, then you'll need to null terminate the string in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

With a TCP socket you don't necessarily receive the whole message with one call to recv. You have to have a way to know whether or not you have received the whole message. One way is to put the message length at the start of the message. Another way is to terminate the ASCII message with a special character (like \n). At the receiving end you have to use the count returned by recv and look at the received data to determine if you have the whole message yet. If not then you need to call recv again to get more of the message.

You are treating the received message as a character array, but character arrays must be terminated with a nul before it is safe to pass them to atoi (or any other C string function):

```
buffer[received_length] = '\0';
```